# Restricting WCF Service access to only localhost

Tags: wcf, iis, localhost

I have three WCF services hosted in IIS and these services are being used by my internal applications(including a WCF service) on the same machine. The need here is to restrict the outside access to WCF service. These three WCF services should be accessible only at localhost, i mean on the same machine and it should not be accessed from other mahcine.
So if i type svc url from other machine : http://myHostingMachine/MyService/Service1.svc ..it should not be accessible. What is the best possible way to achieve this.

In simple way can I restrict access to SCV files using WCF configuration just to localhost??

Comment: which version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this;

- [in IIS itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/136742/iis-7-5-limit-folder-access-to-local-users)
- [By configuring WCF correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360540/configure-wcf-for-localhost-only-listening)
- [use IIS7 and WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx)
- [use named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) [(more info)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184878/expose-a-wcf-service-through-a-named-pipes-binding)
- configure your firewall correctly

Named pipes are probably the way to go

> *When to Use the Named Pipe Transport*
>
> A named pipe is an object in the Windows operating system kernel, such as a section of shared memory that processes can use for communication. A named pipe has a name, and can be used for one-way or duplex **communication between processes on a single machine**.

Comment: changing the WCF configuration is the only option. Is there any way through configuration to restrict the access to svc file itself if the request is not from localhost?

Comment: can i change the IIS settings (assuming i am using the first option) using WCF configuration

Comment: I don't think so, no. If changing the WCF configuration is the only option, you could also change the binding or not?

Comment: here the requirement is just restrict the access to SVC file itself. So binding change is not going to help

Comment: The answer "By configuring WCF correctly" does not contain a link to a solution, it merely refers to the 4th option, named pipes.