# How do I limit my WCF service to only be called by sites on the same servers?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've been asked to write a WCF service which exposes some of our vehicle stock to our other websites.

The only calling clients will be web pages which will be hosted on the same web servers as the WCF service itself.

I'm having real trouble understanding the authentication options (which will be username and passwords stored in SQL) in order to authenticate but also how to limit the service just only be called by our website(s).

I want to limit the service to only be called by sites on the same servers, can I restrict the service to only be accessible by 'itself' and would that address be 127.0.0.1?

I've read loads of articles about this aspect of WCF services and I'm totally baffled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could set a TCP binding on some port then forbid any external access to that port through the firewall settings. I wouldn't try to handle that from the code (waste of time IMHO).

Comment: Do try specifying localhost in WCF service address

Comment: @Chirag specifying localhost isn't helping security. One can always make a call to the distanst serveur providing "localhost" as the domain name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting WCF Service access to only localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333217/restricting-wcf-service-access-to-only-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly old, but I still think [WCF IP Filter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37280/WCF-Service-Behavior-Example-IPFilter-Allow-Deny-A) applies to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Net.NamedPipes binding. It only supports local-machine connections.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF services are IIS-hosted, you can put IP based restriction, like [this](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/locking-down-website-access-by-ip-in-iis7).