# WCF endpoint only on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restricting WCF Service access to only localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333217/restricting-wcf-service-access-to-only-localhost)

I have a WCF method set up for a .NET project.

I can enable the endpoint to work over https and / or http.

However, I only want the HTTP version (`bindingConfiguration="webBinding"`) to work on localhost. Is there a way to restrict this in the web.config?

I had very limited success setting `<endpoint address="localhost/"myproj/mysvc.svc" />` but ultimately didnt work.

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt Which of those links shows discusses restricting it inside web.config?

Comment: I think that this question: "In simple way can I restrict access to SCV files using WCF configuration just to localhost?" is similar. But it looks like you have already received a response that answers your question better than the answer in the link I posted. So please ignore my commment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: [Configure WCF for LOCALHOST-only listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360540/configure-wcf-for-localhost-only-listening)

Try to set the [BasicHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.hostnamecomparisonmode.aspx)  to  `HostNameComparisonMode.Exact`.

or in config file..

```
 <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Binding1"
                     hostNameComparisonMode ="Exact">
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

But better is to use the named pipe binding, which should support whatever message exchange pattern you are using (it supports request-response, as well as the same concurrency and session state modes that WS supports).

From the section of MSDN titled ["Choosing a Transport"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)

Hope this help..